# How to create table of contents if I don't have section at all?

Tags: table-of-contents, enumerate

I have almost 20 pages document where no `\section`, `\subsection` and etc. The reason is it should have plenty of enumerators. Currently the deepest level is 3 - XX.XX.XX. I have done all this stuff with enumerators the main reason to do so it is faster to compile in MikTex LaTeX.(At least, it was so when I have tested it).

For instance,

```
1. Header
1.1. Subheader One
1.2 Subheader Two
1.2.1 SubSub Two
2. Footer
2.1 subFooter One
2.1.1 SubSub One
2.1.2 SubSub Two
```

It is exactly structure I have, having this structure that is done without `\section` element I would like to have table of contents that will automatically generate pages and have possibility to generate pages like 4(1) or 10(8).

To summarize, having enumerators I would like to generate table of contents with automatic addition pages, page numbers may be complex.

Comment: Hm, strange approach. And what you like to have in list of contents? list of contents is intended to collect section, subsection ... titles! With classic structured document your life will much easier as you made it now.

Comment: Is saving compiling time in a 20 page document worth the "trouble"?

Comment: I agree with Zarko: You should not do that! But if you really want to you can manually add entries to the toc with `\addcontentsline{...}{...}{...}`.

Comment: There's got to be something else going on with the build time. I made a 28-page document containing 26 sections, each with one subsection, two subsubsections, and four paragraphs of lorem ipsum. That document took just over 2 seconds to build twice (first run to make the .toc and other auxiliary files, second run to include them in the PDF). Making a normal table of contents should not be a factor on build time.

Comment: I like the sentence "it is faster to compile". Because ... I'm not compiling it, it is like doing dishes with a dishwasher. i don't care how long it takes. If he does it correct. Now you are going to the shop, spending your time looking for soop, etc... and next time you add another dish, you have to go to the shop again. So I say: let the computer do the job, make yourself some coffee and come back again. ;-)

Comment: Normally, the sectioning should not slow down the process. Maybe you are using an obscure or a cluttered package that redefines the sections?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong approach. An enumeration is not a heading. If your editor were Emacs, for the process of making sections from I'd suggest to convert LaTeX to org (Pandoc!), and change in Orgmode the numbered lists to headings and export the whole thing back to LaTeX...

However, it is by far easier to switch to sections, than producing manually a toc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I shall not be proposing any text editor because typing `\section*` takes 5 seconds.

Generally, this is not recommended, but if you **really** must have something very fancy, you might use the [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec) package and the `\addcontentsline` command. Titles should not be formatted by hand: LaTeX can do it perfectly.

Bad example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\LARGE Wondrous secTTion Halibut. Installing \LaTeX
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Halibut. Installing LaTeX}
\end{center}
Use TeXLive.

\begin{center}\large Subsection ``Stealing sheep''. Letterspacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Stealing sheep: font expansion}
\end{center}
Never again.

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Better example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{20pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large}{\thesection}{20pt}{}{}


\begin{document}

\section*{Wonderful section Halibut. Installing \LaTeX}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Halibut. Installing LaTeX}
Use TeXLive.

\subsection*{``Stealing sheep.'' Letterspacing}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Stealing sheep: font expansion}
Never again.

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: A better example]

However, I ask you to consider configuring the style with `titlesec` and **not** using hard-coded stuff.

The best example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{20pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large}{\thesubsection}{20pt}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Wonderful section Halibut. Installing \LaTeX}
Use TeXLive.

\subsection{``Stealing sheep.'' Letterspacing}
Never again.

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: The best example]

Why would someone **not** like this?